# Mysql - self join to check equality

Tags: mysql

I have a table whose structure is as below.

**id, firstname, lastname, address, phoneno**

I need to select all the firstnames and lastnames which are repeated. For example,

- 1 Bob Williams S-Oak st 1234567890
- 2 Rob Williams N-Oak st 1235432222
- 3 Bob Williams S-Pec st 4332122111

I need to make a self join and get the result as Bob Williams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for a self-join.

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, COUNT(*) c
FROM table
GROUP BY firstname, lastname
HAVING c > 1
```

Comment: next time I'm leaving off the `nt` in my answer and winning the race

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. I was thinking of self join. This seems a pretty easy option. Thanks again :)

Comment: @MarcB You could've removed `nt` and added `BY` :)

Answer (score 3):

No need for a self join.

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM yourtable
GROUP firstname, lastname
HAVING cnt > 1
```